# Manage resources generated by other resources

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I am working with someone else's kubernetes application. It has a long-running Deployment whose first action upon beginning to run is to create several additional, non-workload, cluster resources (`ValidatingWebhookConfigurations` and `MutatingWebhookConfigurations` in this case).

I would like for the generated resources to be deleted when their parent Deployment is deleted. Please assume that I don't have control over how the generated manifests are deployed, but do have control over their contents.

Questions:

- Can my goal be achieved with plain kubernetes?

  - In other words, can the generated resources be modified to be deleted when `kubectl delete deployment parent-deployment` is called?
  - This is preferable to handling this via Helm since some people may deploy the application using a different deployment tool.
- Alternatively, is there a good way to handle this with Helm if `parent-deployment` is deployed as part of a helm chart?

  - Can I just add helm's labels to the generated resources to make Helm aware of the new resources?
  - I, personally, will deploy the application using a Helm chart so a Helm-based solution will solve my immediate problem but won't help people who deploy the application using a different method.

Comment: Have a look at owner references and finalizers: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/owners-dependents/

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. Somehow my brain didn't make the connection with finalizers. If you submit an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use owner references and finalizers to create parent/child relationships between resources that allow you to clean up child resources when parent resources are deleted.

Current docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/owners-dependents/